# Decoding gzip (using PHP sockets)

Tags: php, sockets, gzip, last.fm

Ok, so there is this PHP implementation of Last.FM API some guy wrote and I'm using it for a small project of mine. His implementation doesn't request gzipped data from Last.FM servers so I decided to modify his implementation to work with gzip to reduce bandwidth. I have no problem in requesting gzipped data, that works just fine and all the data comes compressed (checked). The problem is decoding it. I'm pretty new with PHP and I was trying to decode it for the last two days but nothing I tried worked. :D

Here is the function that asks for and receives the data. If anyone could please help me make this function decode the data I'd be really grateful.

```
function send ($msg) {
    // Send message over connection
    fwrite($this->handle, $msg);

    $response = array();
    $line_num = 0;
    while ( !feof($this->handle) ) {
        $response[$line_num] =  fgets($this->handle, 4096);
        $line_num++;
    }

    // Return response as array
    return $response;
}
```

where $this->handle is

```
    $this->handle = fsockopen($this->host, $this->port, $this->error_number, $this->error_string);
```

Thank you =)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like...

```
$response='';
while(!feof($this->handle)) {
  $response.=fgets($this->handle, 4096);
}
$response=gzdecode($response);
return explode("\n",$response);
```

Im **assuming that the whole response is gzipped** and not each line individually. If it's each line you just need to change fgets() into gzdecode(fgets())..

Comment: This is valid, with two caveats – gzdecode is trunk only and it unnecessarily puts the whole response in memory before decoding it. The second problem is not so bad, but the first...

Comment: You can use something like `gzinflate(substr($data,10,-8))` instead of `gzdecode($data)`, but the indexes may be off because the size of the headers of the data is variable.

Comment: I have previously tried using gzdecode() and I get "Fatal error: Call to undefined function gzdecode()". After google-ing it I found out gzdecode() will be implemented in php6? (on localhost I have 5.3.0 installed). I also tried using this simple function I found here - http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzdecode.php but it also does not get the job done...

Comment: gzinflate (and also gzuncompress) function gives me "Warning: gzinflate() [function.gzinflate]: data error"

Comment: Artefacto's second followup is the reason - the gz functions do not work on chunks of data - only the whole data stream. If this were a file you could use gzopen(...); while(!gzeof()) { gzread(...); } gzclose(); but from http://php.net/manual/en/filters.compression.php : "they do not provide a means for generalized compression over network streams". Suggest you write it to a local file and use gzopen (the local file may be a filesystem socket though)